# What is better in my case: vector or list?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, vector

I have a function that reads the files in a folder (I am using boost for that). I am also trying to keep only 2 files (they are files of logs, so they are rotated, and I do not want to keep old logs = logs in the third file). I store the files' names in a list, but because the read is not done in the creation time order, I need to sort the list.

I know that

> Vectors are good at:
>
> - Accessing individual elements by their position index (constant time).
> - Iterating over the elements in any order (linear time).
> - Add and remove elements from its end (constant amortized time).

and

> Advantages to list containers:
>
> - Efficient insertion and removal of elements anywhere in the container
>   (constant time).
> - Efficient moving elements and block of elements within the container or even between different containers (constant time).
> - Iterating over the elements in forward or reverse order (linear time).

---

**I am not sure what is the best way to do this: using list or vector?**

Shall I

- use vector and sort it ascending, delete from the end, add new element (at the end), reorder, etc;
  or
- use list and sort ascending it, delete from the beginning, add new element at the end, resort, etc;

---

- *Is sorting needed only at the beginning, because every file name that I insert is the last created?*
- *If the list/vector is sorted, what is the time of resorting it?*
- *If I use `std::is_sorted` is it ok for not sorting every time?*

---

**Some more info:**

Because the file rotation of boost has no "remove file if too many" state, only the "there is enough space on disk", I have implemented this step of keeping the last two files, or removing the oldest every time a new one is created and there are 2 logs files. So every time a new log file is created I am verifying the list of files, and if there are enough (2 or more) just delete the older one(s). Because the names of the files are `logs_%N.log`, I cannot know if the file `logs_X1.log` is older than `logs_X2.log`

> eg: I restart the applications, there are the files logs_51.log, logs_52.log, which one is going to be deleted? Supposing it is going to delete logs_51.log and create logs_0.log, if I restart it again, there will be logs_52.log and logs_0.log. Which one is going to be deleted now?)

That is why I need the sort, because the application may restart, and I read the existing files, completes the one that has more space and then create a new one.

Comment: If there are only two files, what's the purpose of sorting, or even having a container at all?

Comment: I say the difference will not matter enough to worry about it. You are optimizing something that takes very little time. And its not like you will call this billions of times in a loop.

Comment: `use vector and sort it ascending, delete from the end, add new element (at the end), reorder, etc` makes no sense. Inserting at the beginning is much faster than inserting at the end and sorting.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In fact I arrive at a point where the vector/list has 3 elements, then I delete the oldest (the wanted case), but I think this will not change too much your opinion. :)

Comment: @user2079303 Not sure where that advice comes from - inserting at the end of a `vector` is generally faster since it avoids having to shuffle items up.

Comment: @BenHymers since the sorted position of the new element is at the beginning, you have to do the shuffle anyway. And on top of that, O(n log n) comparisons.

Comment: @sop  Ok, so you actually are talking about a 2 element container! There's no way any of the choices you've asked about here are going to make any difference.

Comment: @user2079303 Ok, if the position it'll end up at is the beginning you may be right... but if that's the case I don't understand the need for a sort? That suggested to me that we don't know the position the element will end up at. And why am I still discussing sorting a 2-element container....

Comment: @BenHymers, well, that's how I understood the question. If my interpretation  is not correct, it's still better to search for the correct position first and insert there, rather than sort after. Yeah, considering the size of the container, this question is silly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have used Boost for sorting the files in the last modified manner:

```
bool Logger::compareAccessTime(const std::string& path1In, const std::string& path2In)
{
    return (fs::last_write_time(fs::path(path1In)) < fs::last_write_time(fs::path(path2In)));
}
```

where `fs = boost::filesystem`

And because I have used a list of strings, I have not changed the whole code, but added the `list::sort(compareAccessTime)` when initialising the list. I need that only at the start of the application, because then I add at the end and delete from begin.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case, where the container will have ~2 elements, it doesn't matter one tiny bit. The time spent enumerating files and deleting them will be orders of magnitude slower than your choice of algorithm and data structure. Just put the file names in a `std::vector`, use `std::sort` (which will sort your log file names so that the earliest comes first), then delete the N-2 first items. Job done.

But for some general advice:

These days the general advice seems to be that `std::vector` is better than `std::list` even for many things `std::list` seems like it would be good for, due mostly to the fact that it's contiguous storage which is more cache-friendly.

It's possible to construct benchmarks that'll show `std::list` is faster, but you won't go far wrong if you pick `std::vector` for everything!

If you need to maintain a container over time and always need to be able to remove the smallest/largest element, `std::priority_queue` can be a good idea.

If you need to find the N smallest/largest items in a container, `std::partial_sort` is an algorithm for doing that; it'll be faster than a full `std::sort` because it doesn't waste effort sorting the elements you don't care about.

But as with all general performance questions like this, the only correct answer has to be "try it and see" I'm afraid!

Edit: I originally suggested `boost::circular_buffer` since that's what the problem sounded like, but it's clear now that it's not a good suggestion as ordering needs to be created by sorting, not by insertion order.

Comment: can it be sorted? I need to sort it when creating it

Comment: I've read your new comments and updated question and it looks like `boost::circular_buffer` is actually not what you're looking for - I'll update my answer. If you're looking for an always-sorted container, `std::priority_queue` may be more appropriate. But really, I'd personally implement this by putting the file names in a `std::vector`, sort it with `std::sort`, then iterate over the first N-2 items and delete them; job done. I guarantee you that the enumeration and deletion of files is going to be many orders of magnitude slower than your choice of data structure.

Comment: Also... seriously, don't bother doing this for this problem, but if you encounter a situation where you need to pick the N smallest/biggest items from a container and you need to do it quickly, the algorithm for that may be `std::partial_sort` - it won't waste time sorting the parts of the container you don't need to be sorted. Honestly though for this problem, it's more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

None really here gets it, the guy needs to compare the name of 2 files , not data structure lessons

use the  string::compare  to compare the files, yes it will compare those numbers in the end of your logfiles too so don't worry about that

here is how it works

```
 value=String.Compare(filenameA,filenameB)



  If value<0 then print("filenameA is smaller than filenameB")
  If value>0  then print("a is bigger than b") 
  If value=0  then print("a equals b")
```

oh and about the data structure selection, you don't need to care about efficiency, or performance issues 
I mean you are just indexing 2 files by name a simple and humble array will do the trick

here an a example on how to do it

```
putNewFileMethod(FileType* arrayofFiles,FileType MynewFile)`
{



String nameOfFile0=arrayOfFiles[0].method_that_retrieves_the_filename();
String nameOfFile1=arrayOfFiles[1].method_that_retrieves_the_filename();//you can search for a method of this kind in the docs of the api you are using,`

int value=String.Compare(nameOfFile0,nameOfFile1);

      If( value<0)
        arrayOfFiles[0]=MynewFile;
else    arratOfFiles[1]=MynewFile;


}
```

additional notes :

You can you use a circular array of 2 positions, that would require no sorting on the files, but you mentioned something about restarting your application , so I guess that's not a optimal solution for you,
(if you want an circular array/buffer example just tell me)

Data structures don't come with buildin sorting functions , at least most of them , so you just have to make one of your self

Comment: case you for some reason want to make your life harder by adding random formats on log file title , like log_iLikeRandomNames.log try this date retrieving method , it works by path so you don't have to provide a File object [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nice remark. Actually I have used Boost and `last_write_time()` function, I'll post my approach. And about your answer, I do not really agree with string comparison, the example that I have added the last is the reason why